# Formatting Standard time to ISO 8601 with Electron/NodeJS using Moment

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron, momentjs

I am trying to convert a standard time `October 3, 2020, 9:24 pm` to ISO time using Moment.js and I unfortunately keep getting "Invalid Date". I had a datepicker form that is formatted to the standard time.

Here's the code
`var OutputISO = moment($("#DatePicker").val());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for an extra library to convert a standard time to ISO format, the following expression should work just "out of the box":

```
new Date('October 3, 2020, 9:24 pm').toISOString()
// -> "2020-10-03T19:24:00.000Z"
```

Reference: [Date.prototype.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Therefore, this line of code should also return the proper string, unless there is an issue with the form element ID:

```
let OutputISO = document.getElementById('DatePicker').toISOString();
```